# How to automatic restart node application with nodejs and typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, babeljs, nodemon

I'm setting up a new project with nodejs, express, typescript, and babel. So I use babel for faster transpile typescript code and `etsc` for types checking

When I writing code, I'd like to the application applied changes automatically without me manually restart the application. My solution is running `babel cli` for transpile code with `nodemon`.
My script is like this

```
  "scripts": {
    "ts-check": "tsc --noemit",
    "build-ts": "etsc",
    "build": "rm -rf dist && yarn run build-ts",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel src --out-dir dist --extensions \".ts\"  --source-maps inline",
    "start": "node ./dist/src/index.js"
  },
```

But the problem is the application keeps restart even when I don't make any changes to the code. So how do I solve that?

Is there a better solution for applied changes automatically?

Here is what I got
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is `nodemon` runs only `babel` command and not your `./dist/src/index.js`. And the second problem is `babel` being run transpiles your `.ts` files into `.js` and then `nodemon` notices `.js` files changed and reruns your command (`babel`) that again transpiles your `.ts` files into `.js` ones with new timestamps. And I believe you've got the idea.
So in fact you need two serapate but dependent things: recompile your `.ts` files into `.js` ones, and restart node only when `.js` files changed.
You may achive that with something like that:

```json
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "dev": "babel src --watch --out-dir dist --extensions .ts --source-maps inline & nodemon"
        ...
```

So you're starting simultaneously both `babel` in `watch` mode and `nodemon`. When there are changes in `.ts` files babel will recompile them into `.js` and when there are changes in `.js` files nodemon will restart `node`.

There is a minor drawback however. On the first run while there is no `./dist/src/index.js` file `nodemon` will throw an error. It's not critical, `nodemon` will continue to run. And just after `babel` finished transpiling code `nodemon` will pick up the changes and go on without issues.
Though if you do not want to see that error in console you may include a delay before nodemon starts. Just long enough for `babel` to finish it's first run.

```json
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "dev": "babel src --watch --out-dir dist --extensions .ts --source-maps inline & sleep 5 && nodemon"
        ...
```